# Intellisense not working in SQL Server Management studio. what could be reason?

Tags: intellisense, ssms, sqlclient

I have been working on SSMS 2008 for last 1 month, I have enabled intellisense

[image]

Not sure why but it just does not work. what could be reason?

Comment: are you using script to choose database? `use db_name`. In that case, I faced problem over intellisense and later start choosing database from the list it shows in UI.

Comment: @sundar not using use db_name...

Comment: You're using SSMS 2008 - but is the database you're going against also 2008 or newer? If not, intellisense won't work.... check using `SELECT @@Version` - what version number do you get?

Comment: @marc_s database is SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Well - intellisense **only** works against databases of SQL Server **2008 and newer**.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with Intellisense not working, in both **SSMS version 17.9 and 18.0 and 18.1**, when using **Azure SQL DB**, on accounts that were not dbmanager.

The suggestion from @sundar helps, even if it reports an error

```
Msg 40508, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database.
```